# Google Apps claims my domain is registered but when I try to access it claims it is not

Tags: google-workspace

we have registered one of our domains with Google Apps 2 years ago. However, we didn't even use it. Now if I try to access:

http://google.com/a/mydomain.com

What I see is:

> Server error
>   Sorry, you've reached a login page for a domain that isn't using Google Apps. Please check the web address and try again.

Then I go to Google Apps Standard Edition signup page and type mydomain.com. However, what I get is:

> This domain has already been registered with Google Apps. Please contact your domain administrator for instructions on using Google Apps with this domain.

Is there anyone who can explain me what this inconsistency is caused by and what I can do?

Since Google Apps Standard Edition doesn't grant me to contact with Google, I can't even submit a bug report.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is something you should contact Google about if you're a customer there.

Answer (score 3):

Eek... I believe something like this happened to us on a test domain (I think it took a couple of weeks to be resolved though).  There is an 'emergency' contact for Google.  The only thing I could find was a 'service unusable' contact phone number (shown at our admin page):

> Google Apps phone line available for service unusable issues
>   "Service unusable" is a Google server error that prevents users from accessing a Google Apps online service. By asking that you reserve the phone line for service unusable issues only, we can better ensure that all customers receive an immediate response in emergency situations.
>   
> **(Local):1-800-598-3901
>
>   (Global):1-650-253-7875**

In case that doesn't work try their support and discussion pages:

- http://www.google.com/support/a/
- http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you login to your Primary domain, and not to an alias domain.
If you try to login to an alias domain, that is exactly the error you will get.

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33419